# wirless interface between pc and jn5148 using jennic stack

Tags: eclipse, windows-7

I am newbie. I am having jennic nodes jn5148  ek010 and i am using jennet stack.I am using eclipse and provided libraries on win 7 . I wanted to know that whether wireless interface between these nodes , using jennet, is  possible ,if yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. So please, update your post to clarify what you actually mean.

Some background to the JN5148 boards is that they communicate via the IEEE802.15.4 protocol:
[JN5148 product page](http://www.nxp.com/products/rf/wireless_microcontrollers/JN5148.html)

The IEEE802.15.4 standard provides a MAC and a PHY layer: [Wikipedia reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.15.4). You can use this MAC layer directly or you can use Zigbee, which allows an application interface to the wireless communication: [Jennic's implementation of Zigbee](http://www.jennic.com/products/protocol_stacks/zigbee_pro)

If your question is whether you can communicate from your JN5148 to your PC directly, this is only possible if your PC supports IEEE802.15.4, which it probably doesn't. Otherwise you can always connect one dedicated node to your PC and communicate via a serial interface.

If your question is whether you can connect your nodes to the internet, then the answer is yes. 6LoWPAN is the version of IPv6, which can be communicated over IEEE802.15.4 or other low-power wireless communication: [Wikipedia reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6LoWPAN). In order to connect your 6LoWPAN network to the actual IPv6 internet you need an 6LoWPAN gateway as described here: [Designing a 6LoWPAN Gateway](http://rtcm.inescporto.pt/fileadmin/rtcm/Workshop_11_Fev_11/RTCM_11_Fev_2011_s3p1.pdf)

If I did not answer your question, please clarify what you want to know.